# How can I assign the multiple values to an array Position in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
I array={2,5,7,12} % D is an Image attached
H=[];
for i=1:4
  for j=1:10
    if(D(I(i),j)<=10)  
      H=[H,j];  %H is an array.
    end
  end
end
```

[D matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAXK7.png)

I am getting results like `2    12  5   7   5   6   7   2   12`

I want something like this. I don't know to store it.

```
H(1):2,12
H(2):5,7
H(3):5, 6, 7
H(4):2 ,12
```

Comment: You need to use `cell`, since for `matrix` the number of elements in each row must be equal. `H = {}; ...........H{i} = j;`

Comment: I have tried that but didn't work . It is displaying the last successful value of j.